# PDO PHP string input starting with number ("2abcd") gets trimmed to only number ("2") in $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);

Tags: php, mysql, validation, pdo, prepared-statement

I am using  PDO in PHP. whenever I pass $id = "2abcd" (number with string suffixed)  the query returns Successfully. (with data of $id=2)

in Database :id INT(11), img VARCHAR(100), uname VARCHAR(100)

```
 public static function getImagePath($id) {
    $sql_fetch_opp = "select img from my_user where id=:id";
        $db = DAO::connect();
    try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql_fetch_opp);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $imgPath = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
        return $imgPath;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        Err::log($e);
        throw new MyException(Err::PDO_EXCPTION);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing your `id` column is probably `INT` - and since you've just confirmed that, you should see [Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html); essentially when you convert `2abcd` to an `INT` it simply becomes `2`

Comment: Yes,  how do I prevent this from happening? other than checking $id before passing to the function

Comment: If it is integer then why you are using `2abcd` ?

Comment: What exactly are you _expecting_ to happen?

Comment: This is called through an API, I wish to prevent user from inputting invalid values.

Comment: @C2486 That input is by the User, I do have some checks in Service Layer, but still wish to make even the queries robust to it.

Comment: @PatrickQ I want it to throw PDOException on such invalid inputs

Comment: You should probably validate the data yourself instead of relying on the database to do that for you.

Comment: @jeroen No probably about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to check if the provided value is the same as the value after you cast it to an integer.  If it is not, then throw an exception.

```
public static function getImagePath($id) {
    $sql_fetch_opp = "select img from my_user where id=:id";
        $db = DAO::connect();
    try {
        if((string)$id !== (string)(int)$id)
        {
            throw new PDOException("Invalid id provided");
        }
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql_fetch_opp);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $imgPath = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
        return $imgPath;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        Err::log($e);
        throw new MyException(Err::PDO_EXCPTION);
    }
}
```

Comment: `is_numeric()` or something similar probably makes this a bit easier :-)

Comment: Indeed.  Although that just makes me wonder what the underlying logic for that function is :)

Comment: As this is not actually a PDOException you might like to make that a simple Exception you are throwing

Comment: And its probably more logical to do the checking before wasting time connecting to the database as well

Comment: @RiggsFolly OP explicitly asked for a PDOException to be throw, that's the only reason I did that.

Comment: `if((string)$id !== (string)(int)$id)` can be simply `if($id !== (int)$id)` because this cast is much faster then the is_numeric method

Comment: @RaymondNijland It depends on the source data.

Comment: both methods depends on the source data.

Comment: @RaymondNijland What I'm saying is that we don't know for sure what the datatype of the input `$id` is.  It may technically be a string. If we just do `if($id !== (int)$id)`, then an `$id` value of "2" will fail that check.

Comment: true iam assuming $id is a user input from the $_GET or $_POST array which is always a string type.

Answer (score 0):

[jeroen]:(https://stackoverflow.com/users/42139/jeroen) has given the correct solution,
I need to check

```
 if(!is_numeric($id))
      throw new MyException(Err::INVALID_ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```